# Why Latex doesn't recognize language characters?

Tags: symbols, languages

Im using Latex in Linux, was writing and compiling a text in portuguese, everything was working ok, when suddenly all the words with special characters [ ç á à â ã ] intead of those now i have --compo???o-- words with question marks in editor as well as when compiling, would apreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` into your preamble if you don't have alreay. `UTF-8` encoding should fix the problems with unicode characters.

Comment: Thanks for the support _--mwormser--_, I used: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to write portuguese but also had to change the format of the source-file in the linux command line with: `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 file.tex > newfile.tex ` (newfile is now utf8) and also **change the format of the latex editor (texmaker) in the options to: UTF8**. After doing all these things I can write and compile again in portuguese. The only bad detail is that I couldnt get back the source-text as it was before I still have those question marks in the source-text. Any suggestion I ll apreciate it

Comment: If you do not have a backup copy of your original text you might be out of luck there and have to replace the broken characters manually, sorry.